# HTML Formatting in td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Currently, my jQuery AJAX call returns data to me that looks something like this:

`<html><p><b>My <i>information</i> here</b></p></html>`

So in theory, it should look something like this on my HTML page:

**My *information* here**

However the data is displaying the raw text rather than the stylized html (looks like the top example instead of the bottom example). I'm trying to display this information a `td` or `div`, but neither seem to be displaying properly.

Is it possible to display the styles of the tags instead of the raw text in either a `td` or `div`?

Comment: How are you adding the AJAX loaded code into your page? Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Need to know what you are trying, can you post the code?

Comment: You would need to use the `| raw` identifier in your AJAX code. I had this same issue years ago.

Comment: You need to show the code that is placing the html into the table cell.

Comment: sounds like you are using `text()` as insertion method which would do exactly as mentioned ... whereas using `html()` is what would be needed

Comment: can you please provide ajax call code to review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery **.html()** if your ajax calls return raw html, insert it to the element you want to have the html:

```
var htmlString = '<p><b>My <i>information</i> here</b></p>';
$('#element').html( htmlString );
```

This will insert the html and display not as raw text

[Heres a codepen demo for you](http://codepen.io/mdan89/pen/MwXOPJ)

Comment: Yep this did it. I was trying to add them as `.text()` instead of `.html()`